# How to overcome Out of memory exception in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, out-of-memory

I have big XML file of 6 GB size but i want only a small snippet from several parts of XML file.I used `(XElement)XNode.ReadFrom()` method and worked well earlier.But now the necessary snippet also grown like anything and throwing out of memory exception.How to solve this issue

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    xr.MoveToContent();
    XNamespace un = xr.LookupNamespace("un");
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.NamespaceURI == un && xr.LocalName == "M_ROOT")
        {
            XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile as x64?

Comment: There are also other similar questions out there.

Comment: Is it really necessary to read this file _on_ the device? Can't you do it in a web service?

Comment: @MPelletier OP is using XmlReader, which was the accepted answer in your linked question, and is still running into problems

Comment: @Thomas Weller it worked well in X64, i am testing thoroughly,Does that make any side effects?

Comment: Yes. It does not run on 32 bit systems any more.

Comment: @Thomas Weller other than that any issues

Comment: @MPelletier first understand my question and what i have done,then link the question, and also read Thomas Weller comments

Comment: @Cheesebaron can you elaborate what you have mentioned?

Comment: Such heavy files are best read on the disk, reading via web service using network to serialize would lead to serious performance issues, might take lot of time and again that needs to be hosted in 64 bi process, which cannot be changed for the code above

Comment: Sorry, voting on reopening.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do you think when you just need a small snippet from a big XML file (6 GB size), is it leading to `Out of Memory Exception (OOM)`, for that do you understand:

1. Virtual memory limit on 32 bit system vis-a-vis 64 bit system
2. Did you profile the memory (using Perfmon, UMDH) to understand the pattern

> Let me explain few important aspects:

1. 32 bit system can have maximum virtual memory for the process as `4GB = 2^32 bytes`, which is by processor design, but its not that whole `4 GB` is available to the user process, by default on Windows it is 2 GB for `user process` and 2 GB for `Kernel process`, that's why most of the 32 bit process throw OOM as it gets near 2 GB. This is not completely RAM allocation, it is virtual memory, which includes paged memory on the disk.

> What is same value on 64 bit ?

1. Simple theoretically, 2^64 ~ 16 Exabytes, but that's not the limit which most of the OS can map or hardware can support, but still a huge value for the kind of operation you are doing, even when its beyond 32 bit, but much easily in the 64 bit ambit, where also there's clean separation between user and kernel process memory

> Can 32 bit memory be pumped up for higher memory

1. Yes, there are certain flags in BIOS like /3GB, which can increase user process allocation to 3 GB, but that's the maximum, as it squeeze the Kernel process to 1 GB limit, it runs the risk of failing heavy kernel operations, therefore not usually recommended to tweak the BIOS settings

> How come your process got compiled in both 32 and 64 bit ?

1. System is 64 bit, it is capable of running even 32 bit binaries using WOW64 (Windows on Windows) technology, other way round is not possible

> How to profile

1. Simple use Perfmon (best for such initial analysis) and for a given process monitor Virtual bytes and Private bytes and you will see a linear increase in memory graph, with no de-allocation due to GC, as you are doing none  in the above code and finally consistent OOM around 2GB, it will show value in bytes, divide by 1024*1024 to get the GB value

> What's wrong in your current program ?

1. You mentioned 6 GB file and I see you reading till the very end, so this means everything will get loaded in the memory and for 32 bit process, as it goes upto 2 GB it will lead to OOM

Comment: You describe 4GB = 2^32 as "which is by processor design". That's not correct. Many 32 bit processors can address more than 4 GB and it was actually implemented in some Server OS. It was a design decision by Microsoft. Also, the 2 GB / 3 GB limit is not accurate: it also depends on large address awareness and can reach 4 GB on 64 bit systems.

Comment: I am quite certain you have not tried the points you are trying to refute, nonetheless, which OS maps more than 4 GB for a x86 (32 bit) architecture (x86 and x64 is Intel processor architectures)
It has nothing to do with Microsoft, which has designed systems based on underlying processor, it is not other way round. These are most certainly the memory limits imposed by the processor architecture (x86 and x64). I am 100% right regarding 2 GB and 3 GB limit, have you ever tried this flag on 32 bit system BIOS. Also check out : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx(32 bit limit)

Comment: Also have you tried applying, `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag to a 32 bit process, where do you apply it. Its applied using the assembly linker and most of them will not support it. I have tried it and most of time it doesn't gets applied as Linker simply rejects it. Also please differentiate between pure 32 bit and Wow64, which provides little more leverage to 32 bit process.
Nowadays 32 bit systems are hardly there. For X64 even when processor allow 16 exabytes, Windows 64 bit will not be able to map more than  8 TB, which is software limitation, when processors are fairly advanced

Comment: Why are you saying I have not tried? Some 32 bit versions of Windows Server use PAE to access 64 GB of RAM, so it's clearly not a 32 bit processor limitation. Actually it's in the list that you linked to. And yes, I've successfully applied the LAA flag on 32 bit executables. Not via the linker as you do. Instead I use `editbin` and it works smoothly.

Comment: Though PAE is an interesting feature provided by the 32 bit (x86) processors, enabled by OS, check, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366796.aspx. Though in my understanding this is more of a hack, which tends to modify the address translation, to make the same address space map to a larger RAM (64 / 128 GB). 
Bigger challenge is such features hardly represent a standard and is not widely adopted, 32 bit systems have literally phased out and 64 bit systems doesn't need such features. Nonetheless thanks for good pointer. Does `Editbin` works for Wn32 binaries too ?

Comment: Also check this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141023-00/?p=43783/

As I understand /3GB is for 32 bit and LargeAddressAware is for 64 bit, I have frequently used /3GB

Comment: /3GB is to modify the 32 bit OS to provide 3 GB to the application. LAA is the flag in the application to make use of those 3 GB. On a 32 bit system you need them both together, otherwise it's 2 GB only. Both is not widely used. In my case, it was a special industry, limited to many but old COM components which had the need for 3GB and LAA.

Comment: The LAA flag is in the NT header of an executable, so it won't work for DOS executables, but for Win32 executables. You can use Stud_PE to view it.

Comment: Ok then mostly we used to get the 32 bit binaries with `LargeAddressAware` enabled , therefore just need to enable 3 GB flag to get it working. Thanks for the important Information